# Smooth background image change javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var div = document.querySelector('.content');
var arr = ["pic1_LR.jpg", "pic2_LR.jpg", "pic3_LR.jpg"];

var index = 0;
var iterations = 0;

var updateImage = function () {
if (index >= arr.length) {
index = 0;
iterations++;
}
div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + arr[index] + ')';
index++;
}

var interval = setInterval(updateImage, 2000);
```

Right now it just instantly changes. I want it so that it changes smoothly.

Comment: What do you mean with "smoothly"? That they fade in to each other? As a hint, that would mean that you need two images visible at the same time.

Comment: @RickardElimää yeah I want them to have fade transition in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `transition` CSS property.

```
.content {
  transition: background-image 500ms;
}
```

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.content');
var arr = ["https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513151233558-d860c5398176?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8ZnVuJTIwYmFja2dyb3VuZHxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80", "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579546929662-711aa81148cf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8MXx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&w=1000&q=80", "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/watercolor-textured-background-picture-id887755698?k=6&m=887755698&s=612x612&w=0&h=_yEUF8gLpWjZv5IgwuWkecNVt4X4P7vpuFBKCWIuR44="];

var index = 0;
var iterations = 0;

var updateImage = function () {
  if (index >= arr.length) {
    index = 0;
    iterations++;
  }
  div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + arr[index] + ')';
  index++;
}

var interval = setInterval(updateImage, 2000);
```

```css
.content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: background-image 500ms;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again @iota

Comment: @RagingVids Happy to help.

Comment: would you please mind giving this a look for me:
[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66935859/cannot-change-css-of-a-different-div[link]